Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 wake up immediately (fixed)
Yesterday, I installed a clean installation of Ubuntu 24.04. At first, the sleep feature seemed to work properly. Then I installed some packages (both snap and deb packages). Today, I noticed that Ubuntu wakes up immediately when suspending. I had the same issue also on Ubuntu 22.04.
I have disabled all devices that can wake up the system using the method described here: Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep
So now the output of cat /proc/acpi/wakeup is:
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
IP2P      S3    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
RP02      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
RP03      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
RP06      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
BR1B      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.1
BR2A      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:02.0
BR2B      S4    *disabled
BR2C      S4    *disabled
BR2D      S4    *disabled
BR3A      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.0
BR3B      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.1
BR3C      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.2
BR3D      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.3
RP05      S4    *disabled
LAN0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
BR1A      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
EHC1      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHCI      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
QRP0      S4    *disabled
QR1A      S4    *disabled
QR1B      S4    *disabled
QR2A      S4    *disabled
QR2B      S4    *disabled
QR2C      S4    *disabled
QR2D      S4    *disabled
QR3A      S4    *disabled
QR3B      S4    *disabled
QR3C      S4    *disabled
QR3D      S4    *disabled
RRP0      S4    *disabled
RR1A      S4    *disabled
RR1B      S4    *disabled
RR2A      S4    *disabled
RR2B      S4    *disabled
RR2C      S4    *disabled
RR2D      S4    *disabled
RR3A      S4    *disabled
RR3B      S4    *disabled
RR3C      S4    *disabled
RR3D      S4    *disabled
SRP0      S4    *disabled
SR1A      S4    *disabled
SR1B      S4    *disabled
SR2A      S4    *disabled
SR2B      S4    *disabled
SR2C      S4    *disabled
SR2D      S4    *disabled
SR3A      S4    *disabled
SR3B      S4    *disabled
SR3C      S4    *disabled
SR3D      S4    *disabled

But the problem persists!
The issue may be related to NetworkManager, because just after a wake up, journalctl | grep -i "wake requested" gives
May 16 11:42:41 kant NetworkManager[1648]: <info>  [1715847161.6790] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)

where the time matches with the time of the wake up.
Update 4 (FIX):
I replaced the keyboard with an old PS/2 keyboard I had and this fixed the problem. It's strange, because the previous keyboard worked properly otherwise.
Update 3:
I killed all processes appearing in the output of systemd-inhibit --list except GNOME Shell. One of them was NetworkManager. It didn't solve the problem. journalctl | grep -i "wake requested" doesn't show any new message.
Update 2:
Somebody suggested that I add the following lines to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
sleep-wake=false

and then invoke sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
It wasn't helpful either. And, again, journalctl | grep -i "wake requested" produces
May 16 13:34:05 kant NetworkManager[12491]: <info>  [1715853845.6895] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)

with the time matching the time of wake up.
Update 1:
Based on some information I found on the web, I tried to disable the wake-on-lan feature of network interfaces with sudo ethtool -s INTERFACE_NAME wol d, but it hasn't been helpful.
